# google app engine - connect with android emulator

Tags: android, google-app-engine

Is there any tutorial online which explains how access files from Google app engine using an android application? I'm trying to find online but no luck so far..

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what files you mean, but a while ago I wrote a simple tutorial that shows how to invoke a webservice from android calling into GAE.

http://broschb.blogspot.com/2009/08/android-and-google-app-engine.html

http://broschb.blogspot.com/2009/08/restful-service-on-google-app-engine.html